# Url Copied from one browser is not working in another borwser

Tags: asp.net, url, browser

The problem which i am facing is i have an asp.net web application 
 and when i opened it in any browser like Internet explorer etc 
.When i copied The url and paste that url in any other browser like chrome or firefox the page not opened with all of its content like site map etc .
 I am sharing the snapshots below.
This is the image when i first opened the application through vs2008 in any browser.

 [image: web form](![The image when i first opened the application])

And This is the image when i copy the url and paste it into another Browser
[image: bugy image]![enter image description here]

please help i am a newbie .
Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you coming to this page when you are able to see the left side menu? I mean what is the flow?

Comment: when i start the application from vs2008 a login page is displayed in the browser and after entering username and password i come to this page whose snapshots i ahve uploaded .

Comment: in the login page you are doing some processing which is actually causing the browser to show the menu. when you copy the url your application miss that processing.

Comment: this site map is in masterpage code which is remain static in every content page

Comment: can you give master page code, which prepares the map?

Comment: actually this sitemap is the part of master page which should be displayed in every child page .And within one browser it is shown but when i copy  paste the link in another browser the problem occurs

Comment: If you the page you are visiting requires login than there is a high probability that you are using session underneath the hood. And those sessions are implemented using session cookies, so please check if the page works after login on the same browser.

Comment: yes it is working fine in the same browser after login.

Comment: So basically this is related to some login issue, also try to open that same link in the new tab of the same browser. If its working then I guess it's a session issue.

Comment: but how it will be solved?

Comment: I think @hans answer best describe your situation either remove the login all together or or don't even show part of the page that is still viewable without login. But that will be a design change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are starting the web-app in one browser. There you log in and navigate to some page within your app. Then you copy the url of that new page and past it in a different browser.

This means you will be accessing the same page, but without logging in. Is that really what you want? (If so, why the login?)

Maybe you should detect that the user is not logged in, and redirect to the login page. You could even remember the original url, to get that user back to the page he originally wanted after logging in.

Comment: yes exactly i want to do the same as u describe so i  what i have to do for this should the page _loda event  check for cookies or anything else.

Comment: @jahanzaibjahanzaib - It depends on how you validate that login. If you built your own, store something in Session and check that.